# CakePHP routing not work with switching language?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have :

```
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('language' => 'en|zh'));
Router::connect('/:language/:controller', array('action' => 'index'), array('language' => 'en|zh'));
Router::connect('/:language', array('controller' => 'welcome', 'action' => 'index'), array('language' => 'en|zh'));
```

I want to add one more route like below:

```
Router::connect('/profile', array('controller' => 'userProfile', 'action' => 'index'));
```

When I go to : www.xxxxx.com/profile , it work as normal but when I go to www.xxxxx.com/en/profile , I receive an error is missing controller. 
How can I do to go to the www.xxxxx.com/en/profile without got any errors?

Please help! Thank you in advanced for any helps!

Comment: just see your code and think for a second what is common in all above routes but missing in new one.

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean? I am not very good of English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare that route line two time.

```
Router::connect('/profile', array('controller' => 'userProfile', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/:language/profile', array('controller' => 'userProfile', 'action' => 'index'), array('language' => 'en|zh'));
```

Use that way and let me know your thoughts regarding for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Router::connect('/:language/profile', array('controller' => 'userProfile', 'action' => 'index'), array('language' => 'en|zh'));
```

Comment: your code produce like: www.xxxxx.com/en/userProfile not  www.xxxxx.com/en/profile is what I want. It show the controller name not the alias we used.

Comment: place this line on above the three lines instead of at bottom, and do reply if this works

Comment: echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'userProfile', 'action' => 'index')); This is my user profile link, so the first time when click it produce www.xxxxx.com/userProfile but when I rename it by my hand to www.xxxxx.com/en/userProfile and refresh it work and also www.xxxxx.com/en/profile is also work. So do you have any solution to change it to www.xxxxx.com/profile at the first click?